# How to add ops to history for "undo" functionality?

Tags: quill

I'm tryingt to add an "undo" button to my quill editor.

However, I'm not sure how I can undo something I've added programmatically like this:

```js
quill.deleteText(range.index, range.length);
quill.insertEmbed(range.index, Annotation.blotName, data, "api");
```

I red something about an ops table but I can't find anything. Do I have to add the returning deltas to the history or something? If so.. how?